# Best option for object-per-line storage in python

Tags: python, json, msgpack

Currently I'm storing a bunch of records (nested dictionaries of stuff) as JSON record-per-line in a file (for a machine learning task). Reading them is a bottleneck, so I'm looking for a faster storage format. So far I looked at pickle and msgpack, but both produce newlines in the encoding process that make them a non-starter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any particular reason you need one record per line? Why not just pickle the record list itself, and not care _how_ it's stored, as long as the computer can read it?

Comment: Try cPickle if you're looking for something a little faster.

Comment: Faster storage format might be a [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive). Side note: I once needed to load a large pickled dictionary that took 5 minutes to load; using [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) reduced the time to 30 seconds or less.

Comment: @Kevin, need record per line so that I can easily process ranges in the file.